# POST method not sending data from JavaScript to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have some data stored in local storage that I want to send to a database. This is the JS code:

```
function sendData() {
  let input = 'new input';
  localStorage.setItem('spins', input);
  // Get user_id from session or wherever it's stored
  var user_id = <?php echo isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : 'null'; ?>;

  if (user_id) {
    var value1 = localStorage.getItem('data');
    var value2 = localStorage.getItem('spins');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'update_values_to_database.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        try {
          var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          if (data.success) {
            localStorage.setItem('data', data.data);
            localStorage.setItem('spins', data.spins);

          } else {
            console.error('Failed to retrieve values from the database.');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Code to handle the error
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
          window.location.href = "update_values_to_database.php";
        }
      }
    };
  }
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    user_id: user_id,
    value1: value1,
    value2: value2
  }));
}
```

And this it the PHP

```
<?php
include("database.php");

// Retrieve data from the POST request
var_dump($_REQUEST);
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];

// Update values in the database for the given user_id
// Modify this query according to your database schema
$query = "UPDATE users SET data = ?, spins = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $value1, $value2, $user_id);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
}
?>
```

Both the file containing the JS code and that containing the PHP code are in the same directory. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could someone tell me what the error could be?
Thanks in advance.

I've tried logging the error and it's saying that the 'user_id', 'value1' and 'value2' keys are undefined and when I var_dump the $_REQUEST it returns an empty array. When I've made sure that all the variables being sent to the PHP file are being defined correctly.

Comment: This line that starts with `var user_id = ` is problematic (in javascript) because you echo out *$_SESSION['user_id']* to javascript without having it go in between quotes. Open you browser console to see errors.

Comment: are you sure those values have any data at all the moment before you sent them in your js? try debugging your code

Comment: PHP doesn't convert JSON to `$_POST`.

Comment: `xhr.send()` should be inside the `if` block.

Comment: Better would be to move into the 21st century and use `fetch()`.

Comment: Fetch would be harder for noob to debug